# What should I set in maximumFractionDigits to minimize data loss?

Tags: ios, swift, formatting

## Introduction

I noticed the `NumberFormatter#maximumFractionDigits` default is 3.

I have confirmed:

```
import Foundation

let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .decimal
print(nf.maximumFractionDigits) //=> 3
nf.string(for: Decimal(string: "100.1111111")) //=> "100.111"
```

## I have tried to set Int.max

I set `Int.max` to `maximumFractionDigits`:

```
import Foundation

let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .decimal
nf.maximumFractionDigits = Int.max
nf.string(for: Decimal(string: "100.1111111")) // => "100"
```

Why!? become `"100"`!?

## In my research

I read `Foundation > NSNumberFormatter > NumberFormatter` source code:

> open var maximumFractionDigits: Int

I have confirmed `maximumFractionDigits` data type is `Int`.

## Question

How to set max into `maximumFractionDigits`?

I want to show a server response without loss, as much as possible.
of course, a server response is `String` in `json`. But all most calculation in ios app with `Decimal` from the `String`. So this goal is to convert `Decimal` to `String` for `UILabel`.

- Q1. `nf.maximumFractionDigits = Int.max`. Why loss data? this is bug on `NumberFormatter`?
- Q2. How to set max into `maximumFractionDigits` correct?

## Goal

I want to minimize data loss.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? You are trying to add 9223372036854775807 fraction digits to your string

Comment: @Dabus I add I want to this.

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi what use case that needs this ??

Comment: What is your goal here? What result do you want when you convert a number to a string? You are converting a string into another string. You say you want no loss. So why bother with any conversion?

Comment: @rmaddy I add the goal.

Comment: `let someString = String(someDouble)` That wouldn't be present a pretty picture if you are going to display that on your UI

Comment: @user1046037 this app not use `Double`, use `Decimal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Q1. nf.maximumFractionDigits = Int.max. Why loss data? this is bug on NumberFormatter?***

When not clearly documented, every `Int` parameter may have a limitation depending on the implementation details. If you passed a value exceeding this limitation, a runtime error might cause crash, or might be silently ignored, all such things depend on the implementation detail.

As far as I tested, the maximum number you can set to `maximumFractionDigits` is the same value with `Int32.max`.

```
let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .decimal
nf.maximumFractionDigits = Int(Int32.max)+1
print(nf.string(for: Decimal(string: "123.45678901234567890123456789012345678"))!)
//->123
nf.maximumFractionDigits = Int(Int32.max)
print(nf.string(for: Decimal(string: "123.45678901234567890123456789012345678"))!)
//->123.45678901234567890123456789012345678
```

You can call it *a bug*, but, the maximum significant digits which `NumberFormatter` can handle is 38-digit, of `Decimal`. Who want to make a precise definition for values more than millions of times bigger than expected practical values?

***Q2. How to set max into maximumFractionDigits correct?***

As noted above, the significant digits held in `Decimal` is 38. You can write something like this:

```
let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .decimal
nf.usesSignificantDigits = true
nf.maximumSignificantDigits = 38
print(nf.string(for: Decimal(string: "123.45678901234567890123456789012345678"))!)
//->123.45678901234567890123456789012345678
```

Comment: I really liked your explanation. I needed this working properly so I dug into this a little bit more and found out that as of today, running Xcode 12, Swift 5.3, the limit seems to be 36 decimal points. However, interestingly enough, if you create a Decimal(string: "<enter 37 or more digits here>", it truncates to 36 the first 36 digits. Also interesting that if you set maximumSignificantDigits = 36, it won't take 36 digits, but less than that. So I set `Int(Int.max)` in that field, and know I'll get up to 36 digits of precision. 